# Django - Rating on Multiple Criteria: Model Formset?

Tags: python, django, rating, django-forms

I have a content that I'd like to rate on multiple criteria.
Imagine this kind of model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Criteria(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  content = models.ForeignKey(Content)

class ContRate(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, help_text="Who rated ?")
  crit = models.ForeignKey(Criteria)
  rate = models.DecimalField()
```

The user has a page displaying the content.
From this page, he can also rate the content on the criterias set

[image: Rating Criterias]

Question are:
Do you suggest to use a [Model Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) for this purpose ?
Or should I do a simple Ajax form to post the ratings ?
Any why should I do this ?

Comment: is `ContRate.crit` a foreign key to `Criteria`? What is `DubCrit`?

Comment: Sorry yes it's `Criteria`, I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) for this kind of problem although you are not going to use `my_formset.is_valid()` nor `my_formset.save()` but because it ease the forms construction in the view and the render in the template. 
No need to worry with the form prefixes etc.

Your `Ajax` call on the `onclick` event (fired by a click on a star) should call a view with the `ContRate` `pk` (if present) and the `rate` as parameters.

The view will instanciate a `ContRateForm` (the same used in your previous `modelformset_factory`) whith those parameters, use the usual mechanisms of `ModelForm` validation and database insert/update and finally render a `json` response.